# Use numpy array as arguments for print()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am struggling on a very simple thing.

I would like to print a string with a certain format:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([123.456789, 1.23456, 12.3456])
print("My First number is %3.4f, second %1.2f and third %2.9f" % array)
```

"array" is an numpy array and include the arguments (size: (1,3)) I'd like to print. But I am getting the following error message:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

This works fine

```
array = (123.456789, 1.23456, 12.3456)
print("My First number is %3.4f, second %1.2f and third %2.9f" % array)
```

But I do have my data as an numpy array. Is there a simple way to convert the array to use the values as arguments for formatted printing pint()?

Comment: `array = tuple(array)` Just add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass to tuple:

```
print("My First number is %3.4f, second %1.2f and third %2.9f" % tuple(array))
```

Or use the [new format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
array = np.array([123.456789, 1.23456, 12.3456])
print("My First number is {:3.4f}, second {:1.2f} and third {:2.9f}".format(*array))
>> My First number is 123.4568, second 1.23 and third 12.345600000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The "new format" does best what I want.

Answer (score 0):

the % formatter expects a tuple if there are multiple items to format into the string, this should fix it

```
 print("My First number is %3.4f, second %1.2f and third %2.9f" % (array[0],array[1],array[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because both are not same object.
that is the first array is numpy.ndarray

and second array which works is tuple.

so

in order to run the first numpy.ndarray try the following line

array1 = np.array([123.456789, 1.23456, 12.3456])

print("My First number is %3.4f, second %1.2f and third %2.9f" , array1[0], array1[1],array1[2])